# Почему при отправке сообщения с кириллицей в Телеграм боте не работает Inline Keyboard?

Tags: telegram-bot, http, micropython

**Здравствуйте!**

Писал недавно Telegram бота на M5Stack (не спрашивайте). Бот должен работать на [*HTTP запросах*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage).

В свою очередь они работают через urequest - модуль MicroPython, на котором работает M5Stack.

В свою очередь дошло до написания кода для отправки сообщений с [*Inline Keyboard*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) [(кнопки под сообщением)](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#inline-keyboards). С сообщениями с латинскими буквами всё идеально работало:

```
urequests.request(method='POST', url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage', json={"chat_id":chat_id, 
"text": "HELLO! \nThis is test.",
"reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard":
[[
{"text": "TEST1", "callback_data":"A1"}, 
{"text":"TEST2", "callback_data":"B1"}
]]}}, headers={})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоило только написать что либо на кириллице, то Inline Keyboard просто исчезал!

```
urequests.request(method='POST', url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage', json={"chat_id":chat_id, 
"text": "Привет!",
"reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard":
[[
{"text": "TEST1", "callback_data":"A1"}, 
{"text":"TEST2", "callback_data":"B1"}
]]}}, headers={})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также это не работало и с [*Unicode*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5):

```
urequests.request(method='POST', url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage', json={"chat_id":chat_id, 
"text": "\u0430\u0431",
"reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard":
[[
{"text": "TEST1", "callback_data":"A1"}, 
{"text":"TEST2", "callback_data":"B1"}
]]}}, headers={})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удивительно, но неожиданно клавиатура заработала при одной русской букве!

```
urequests.request(method='POST', url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage', json={"chat_id":chat_id, 
"text": "ф",
"reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard":
[[
{"text": "TEST1", "callback_data":"A1"}, 
{"text":"TEST2", "callback_data":"B1"}
]]}}, headers={})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перерыв интернет, оказалось, что люди обычно пишут на готовых модулях для ботов (для c++, python и т.д.) или им встречаются другие подобные проблемы (исчезают некоторые кнопки, не работает кириллица на самих кнопках), а такой проблемы как у меня нет.

Ссылка на API Telgram находится в начале вопроса.

Может кто-то встречал подобную проблему или знает как её решать?